# Is it possible to get TeamCity to stop & restart Amazon EC2 instances for build agents?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, teamcity, teamcity-7.0, ec2-api-tools

I have TeamCity (7.0.2) successfully spinning up an EC2 VM from a custom AMI, running our build, and sending back the build artifacts.

However, even when I used to do this with older TeamCity versions, I was always unhappy with the notion that it simply terminates the instances after they are done, and then creates new instances using the configured AMI next time a build agent is needed.

Can I get TeamCity to issue "stop" commands instead, followed by "start" commands? This has a tonne of advantages - quicker spin-up time, allowing for named instances in the agent stats, and saving the Mercurial clone to EBS for the next build are just three.

*p.s. I guess I could use chained builds to call the EC2 API directly rather than use the in-built cloud support, but that sounds like a lot of work and feels flaky*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We plan to provide support of EBS instances start stop in TeamCity 7.1
Please vote for [TW-16419](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-16419)

TeamCity 7.0 may leak EBS volumes [TW-12517](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12517)

Comment: Thanks, is that feature in the 7.1 EAP yet? I guess if I knew a rough timeline I'd know whether it's worth me figuring it out via chained configurations and blogging about it for others in the meantime :)

Comment: Looks like that issue has been marked fixed, so I'd guess it's in the EAP soon ..